# write php if statement inside html element I create with php

Tags: php, html

I use php to create html elements based on documents from a mongodb collection .

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('category'=>$ProductType)); //gets my items 
//then for each item create an html element 
foreach($cursor as $doc){
   echo " 
         <div class= 'product'>
              <h2> ".doc["title"]." </h2> //add product name property as element 
              //here i want to check if my product has a price then display the price 
              //but i do not know how to use if statement here  
        </div>
      ";
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to use an if statement inside an `echo  " ...";` where an html element is created .

This is what I am trying to do  :

```
if(doc['price']!=0){
   echo <h2> ".doc["price"]." </h2>
 }
```

Comment: You don't. End your `echo`, add your `if`, resume your `echo`

Comment: That's invalid code btw, `echo " <div class= "product">` Escape your quotes. And it should most likely be `$doc["title"]` with a `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start and stop the echo any time and then restart it

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('category'=>$ProductType)); //gets my items 
//then for each item create an html element 
foreach($cursor as $doc){
   echo "<div class= "product">
            <h2>$doc[title]</h2>";
    if($doc['price']!=0){
        echo "<h2>$doc[price]</h2>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Might also want to fix the quotes in `"<div class= "product">`, change `doc[title]` to `{$doc['title']}` and `$doc[price]` to `{$doc['price']}`